# How to limit Google Analytics results with oocharts.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using oocharts (http://oocharts.com) to put some Google Analytics data on a marketing dashboard application I'm making. So far it's working pretty well, but I can't seem to figure out how to limit and sort the results that are showing in a table format.

For example, I'm listing the keywords from Google using the HTML API, so my query looks like this:

```
<div 
data-oochart='table' 
data-oochart-start-date='30d' 
data-oochart-metrics='ga:visits,Visits' 
data-oochart-dimensions='ga:keyword, Keyword' 
data-oochart-profile='00000000'>
</div>
```

This shows me the maximum list of keywords from the last 30 days, which is 500. That is way too long. I need to limit this list to the top 10 keywords, and sort them descending (most often used keyword at the top) but I can't find anything in the documentation about how to accomplish that.

Edit: I'm also trying the javascript query which is below. I get the same results, but I think it may be more configureable (https://github.com/OOcharts/js):

```
oo.load(function(){
    oo.setTableDefaults(
    {   
        page:'enable',
        pageSize: '10',
        sort: 'enable',
        width:'600',
    });

var table = new oo.Table("00000000", "30d");
    table.addMetric("ga:visits", "Visits");
    table.addDimension("ga:keyword", "Keyword");
    table.draw('table3');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used OOCharts but by diging around in the code for [oocharts.js](https://github.com/OOcharts/js/blob/master/oocharts.js) it looks like you can send a sort by doing this:

```
table.setSort("ga:visits");
```

Note: Sorting direction defaults to ascending and can be changed to descending by using a minus sign (-) prefix on the requested field.

This should set your max rows returned:

```
table.setMaxResults("10");
```

Check the code you should be able to find everthing you need there.   You could also have checked the documentation they give you on there site.  http://docs.oocharts.com/

Comment: no dice. Both return the error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setMaxResults' (or setSort)

Comment: try with as a string table.setMaxResults("10");  And check there documentation they have examples of how to use the API.

Comment: Same error. I did find how to set options via the Google Visualization API in the docs. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I learned that OOcharts uses [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) to render these charts, graphs and tables. Therefore, using the Visualization [table options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#Configuration_Options) does what I need.

```
oo.setTableDefaults({
page:'enable',
pageSize: '10',
sort: 'enable',
sortAscending: false,
sortColumn: 1,
allowHtml: true,
width:'600'
});
```

There are a lot more options that can be used here as well.